# Getting a Meta from Multiple Meta

Tags: post-meta, rest-api

i want getting a meta value from multiple meta

i getting meta by :

```
$data['cd_meta'] = get_post_meta( $p->ID, 'cd_meta', true);
```

but cd_meta is a multiple meta and i need just one specific meta from it

how Can get it ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by **`cd_meta is a multiple meta`**? Do you mean `cd_meta` has multiple values in a single row (like a serialized array) or do you mean there are multiple `cd_meta` rows for a single post?